# Message Digest java

Tags: java, digest, message-digest

I was not aware of the `MessageDigest` class before. I am now trying to understand a segment of code and the documentation is not helping me much.

```
MessageDigest digest = Crypto.sha256();

digest.update(last.getSign());
byte[] SignHash = digest.digest(publicKey);
```

According to the java documentation:

> "update" Updates this `MessageDigest` using the given `byte[]`

"digest" Performs the final update and then computes and returns the final hash value for this MessageDigest.

Question 1: What does "updates using the given byte[]" really mean?

Question 2: What is the final update performed by "digest" ?

Does the above mean `SignHash=sha256(last.getSign()` concat (some padding of public key)) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think of the MessageDigest class as if updating it is really appending more bytes to an internal buffer. Now once you're done, you use the digest method to create a hash of all the bytes appended to the buffer.

The naming might seem a bit strange (I certainly think that "appendBytes" and "createHash"/"createDigest" would have been better), but think about the MessageDigest instance, which internal state you **update** with more bytes, until you finally generate the **digest**.

Comment: So with update(last.getSign()), the bytes of Sign are appended to an internal buffer, so far so good. Question 1 clear.  What is the meaning of the input parameter of digest? For example, what is a possible difference between a call of digest() and digest(bytes[]) on the same object?

Comment: The first variant completes the hash computation, the second variant does a last update of the given bytes, then it completes the hash computation (sort of a short cut).